# integrate nutch 2.3.1 with solr 6.4.1 , something wrong with indexing job

Tags: java, solr, nutch

lately i am learn Nutch, when i finished Nutch an Solr set up. I want to try crawling with Nutch and indexing to Solr. some error happen when indexing job. the error is below:

```
SolrIndexerJob: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException:


Expected content type application/octet-stream but got text/html;charset=iso-8859-1.


at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:455)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:197)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:117)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.commit(SolrServer.java:168)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.commit(SolrServer.java:146)
at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.commit(SolrIndexWriter.java:146)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.commit(IndexWriters.java:124)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:186)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:202)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:211)
```

i will appreciate it if anyone could give me some advice. thanks in advance.

Comment: when i run command bin/crawl urls http://localhost:8983/solr 2 , the above errors heppen, but when i change the command to  bin/crawl urls http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1 2 , no more error happen , but the data from crawling from nutch ,seems no pooling to solr.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify Nutch a Solr url of collection or core, so url `http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1` makes sense. But you should use Nutch's [suggestions versions](http://nutch.apache.org/) of each tools to make the total ecosystem working.

```
Apache Avro 1.7.6
Apache Hadoop 1.2.1 and 2.5.2
Apache HBase 0.98.8-hadoop2 (although also tested with 1.X)
Apache Cassandra 2.0.2
Apache Solr 4.10.3
MongoDB 2.6.X
Apache Accumlo 1.5.1
Apache Spark 1.4.1
```

I will suggest to use `Solr-5.2.1` as its pretty latest than `4.10.3` and I've made it working in my project. And as I can remember, I encountered the same exception as you when trying to use Solr 6+.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you , I will have a test for this